# How to change the size of pictures in a javascript array for a slideshow?

Tags: javascript

The array is for a javascript slideshow and the array contains many different URL sources for pictures.
How can the sizes of these pictures be changed so that all of them are the same height and width?

```
var photos=new Array()
var photoslink=new Array()
var which=0
//define images. You can have as many as you want:
photos[0]="http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg" 
photos[1]="http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg" 
photos[2]="http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg" 
//Specify whether images should be linked or not (1=linked)
var linkornot=0
//Set corresponding URLs for above images. Define ONLY if variable linkornot equals "1"
photoslink[0]="http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg"
photoslink[1]="http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg"
photoslink[2]="http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg"
```

How can the sizes of these pictures be changed so that all of them are the same height and width?

Comment: You haven’t put any semicolons (`;`) at the end of your lines. Be careful with that…

Comment: This is really a CSS question.

Answer (score 0):

First, creating an array like this: `var myArray = [];` is more concise.

Your array is not pictures but rather strings which are the urls of pictures.  Therefore, from your current code you can't do what you're asking.

Here is an example of sizing the images by turning them into img tags and appending them to the body:

```
var photos = [
  "http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg",
  "http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg",
  "http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg"
];

var photoslink = [
  "http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg",
  "http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg",
  "http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg"
];

// Create an array of img elements and append them to the body
photos.forEach(function (photoUrl, index) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = photoUrl;
  img.height = '100';
  img.width = '225';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You must do that in the HTML. You can set the height and width with JavaScript or css. I have created some extra code to help you out.

Here it is:

```js
var photos = new Array();
var photoslink = new Array();
var which = 0;

//Define images. You can have as many as you want:

photos[0] = "http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg";
photos[1] = "http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg";
photos[2] = "http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg";

//If you wish to have a image not linked, insert a empty string instead.

photoslink[0] = "http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/376451/koala-bear-profile.jpg";
photoslink[1] = "http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140731_meihuan_ZA_7836_600.jpg";
photoslink[2] = "http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/1/red-fox-hunting_6159.jpg";

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("slideshow").src = photos[which];
  document.getElementById("slideshowLink").href = photoslink[which];
  if (which > photos.length - 2) {
    which = 0;
  } else {
    which += 1;
  }
}, 2500);
```

```html
<a id='slideshowLink' target='_blank'>
  <img id='slideshow' alt='Loading Slideshow...' height='250px' width='400px' border='1'>
</a>
```